# Highlighting a row in a JSF page is not working

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsf-2

I want to highlight a row in a JSF table. This is the code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" var="item">


                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" />
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              $("tr").not(':first').hover(
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","#787878");
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","");
              }
            );
        </script>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I move the cursor on column 1, 2 and 3 the highlighting works

[image]

But when I move the cursor on column 4, 5 and 6 the rows are not highlighted.

[image]

I don't find why the rows are not highlighted. Can you help me to find the mistake?

Best wishes

**EDIT** This is the clean HTML code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
            <title>DX-57 History Center</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/css/themes/nvidia.com/images/favicon.ico" />
            <link href="resources/css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/default.advanced.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <!--[if lt IE 7]&gt;
            &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;js/jquery/jquery.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
            &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;js/jquery/jquery.dropdown.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
            &lt;![endif]-->
            <!-- / END -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script></head><body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal" style="margin: 0 auto">
                <li><a href="/SR_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserNav.jsf" class="dir">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Dashboard.jsf">Dashboard</a></li>
                    </ul>       
                </li>
                <li><a href="Sessions.jsf" class="dir">Sessions</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Application.jsf" class="dir">Application</a>
                    <ul>                
                        <li><a href="Glassfish.jsf">Glassfish</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Linux.jsf" class="dir">Linux</a>                   
                </li>
                <li><a href="Database.jsf" class="dir">Database</a>                    
                </li>                   
            </ul>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"><img src="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" alt="Dashboard" style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/HM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Sessions.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />


                        <!-- The sortable data table --><table id="form:dataTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/HM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:j_idt15':'form:dataTable:j_idt15'},'');return false">Account Session ID</a></th>
<th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:j_idt18':'form:dataTable:j_idt18'},'');return false">User ID</a></th>
<th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:j_idt21':'form:dataTable:j_idt21'},'');return false">Activity Start Time</a></th>
<th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:j_idt24':'form:dataTable:j_idt24'},'');return false">Activity End Time</a></th>
<th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:j_idt27':'form:dataTable:j_idt27'},'');return false">Activity</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1313</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>Sun Apr 08 20:21:44 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Sun Apr 08 20:21:46 EEST 2012</td>
<td>test

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>23</td>
<td>werw</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:14 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:16 EEST 2012</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>231257</td>
<td>323r</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:51 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:21:05 EEST 2012</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>231432</td>
<td>23223r23</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:41 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:55 EEST 2012</td>
<td>32r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>232</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>Mon Apr 09 15:13:33 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Mon Apr 09 15:13:37 EEST 2012</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2323165</td>
<td>2r23r</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:49 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:21:04 EEST 2012</td>
<td>3r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>232337</td>
<td>3r</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:46 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:21:01 EEST 2012</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>232388</td>
<td>323r</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:44 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:59 EEST 2012</td>
<td>r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>233222</td>
<td>32r23r2</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:42 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:57 EEST 2012</td>
<td>32r23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>23329</td>
<td>2323</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:20:47 EEST 2012</td>
<td>Tue Apr 10 15:21:02 EEST 2012</td>
<td>r2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


                        <!-- The paging buttons --><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt30" value="first" disabled="disabled" /><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt31" value="prev" disabled="disabled" /><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt32" value="next" /><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt33" value="last" />Page 1 / 2
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->1<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:j_idt36:1:j_idt37':'form:j_idt36:1:j_idt37'},'');return false">2</a>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page --><label for="form:rowsPerPage">
Rows per page</label><input id="form:rowsPerPage" type="text" name="form:rowsPerPage" value="10" maxlength="3" size="3" /><input type="submit" name="form:j_idt41" value="Set" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="4271939619595356833:-5469736783226522469" autocomplete="off" />
</form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              $("tr").hover(
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","#787878");
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","");
              }
            );
        </script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you supply if there's an error in the javascript console? You can check it in Firefox and Chrome without an addon, in Chrome it is in Developer Tools. If there exists an error or not while your mouse moves, please put that information

Comment: Could that be any of the styles in DIV issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second DIV layer - settingsdiva

Answer (score 2):

You can also use these js function call :

```
onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1';" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'"
```